# "Simple problem" to find order of a product in a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let a and b be elements of a group, with $a^2 = e, b^6 = e $ and $ ab =b^4  a $ . Find the order of ab, and
express its inverse in each of the forms $a^mb^n$ and $b^ma^n?$

Though it seems very simple I'm unable to find a power such that $(ab)^x =e$. Please help.

Im all confused with this problem.

**PS: to put  in context, this question was asked for
 maths optional UPSC IAS  exam in India**

Comment: For all we know $ab$ could be equal to $e$, hence of order $1$.

Comment: $(ab)^{2} = ab\cdot ab = b^{4}a\cdot ab = b^{4}a^{2}b = b^{4}eb = b^{5}$.

Comment: Why do you think that $ab=(ab)^4$? If so, then the order of $ab$ would be $1$ or $3$.

Comment: @BillWallis i dont understand the operation is $ xy=y^4x $, how can you simply multiply $b^4a$  and  $ab$??

Comment: @johny You are given that $ab = b^{4}a$. Thus, any time you see $ab$ you can replace it with $b^{4}a$, and vice versa. This means that the product $(ab)^{2} = abab$ is equal to the product $b^{4}aab$ by replacing (one of) $ab$ with $b^{4}a$.

Comment: @johny Exact duplicate was located by putting the relations into [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%5E2%3De%24%2C%20%24b%5E6%3D%5C%20e%24%2C%20%24ab%3Db%5E4a%24&p=1) search.  Please look for your problems before you post them. There was more than one duplicate, although at least one of them will probably be deleted soon.

Comment: @johny And I suppose the fact it came from a national exam in India is relevant context, but the fact that it selects bureaucrats and only passes 0.01% of people is *completely irrelevant*, I think. Please don't add clutter like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $b^6=e$ and $ab = b^4a$ we can conclude $b^3 = e$: we have
$$
b^3 = a^{-1}(aba^{-1})^3a = a^{-1}(b^4)^3a = a^{-1}b^{12}a = a^{-1}ea = e.
$$
Hence, $ab = b^4a = ba$, i.e. $a$ and $b$ commute. Now, it is easy to see that $(ab)^6 = e$. From this, we can only conclude $\lvert ab\rvert \in \{1,2,3,6\}$.

For the second part of the question: Notice that $(ab)^6=e$ implies $(ab)^{-1} = (ab)^5 = a^5b^5 = ab^2 = b^2a$. (Here we have used $a^2 = b^3 = e$ and $ab = ba$.)

Comment: The conclusion that  $b^3=e$ is correct. The conclusion that the original group $G$ is isomorphic to $H=\langle a,b\ |\ a^2=b^3=e, ab=ba\rangle\simeq\mathbb{Z}_6$ is wrong. Note that the trivial group satisfies all requirements (the OP never stated that $a\neq b$ or that $b\neq e$). The correct conclusion is that there is a group epimorphism $H\to G$ meaning $G$ is a quotient of $H$ making the order $|ab|$ a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Claudius how did you made $b^3$ complicated like that, I didnt get that step. Why you people are taking $ab=b^4a $ whenever you like and at other times simply multiplying it as it is ab. I mean inside the bracket, why didnt you expand like $ba^{-1} = a^{-4} b$? Thats my confusion sometimes it's taken as though there is a binary operation a*b , other times simply as ab. Its confusing me.

Comment: @johny There's an implicit, standard assumption that $xy$ is the same as $x*y$. Also you cannot expand $ba^{-1}$ because there's no formula for that. Your formulas are precisely about two fixed elements $a,b$ and their product $ab$, nothing else. Unless there's an explicit statement "for all $a,b$" and there's no such thing.

Comment: Also after getting $b^3 = e$ why cant we just take $(ab)^6 = $$(a^2)^3$$(b^3)^2$ =e. What is the need to prove ab = ba?

Comment: @johny The same thing: $b^3=e$ is a formula about $b$ **only**. You cannot substitute $ab$ for $b$ because it doesn't hold for $ab$. To make that substitution valid you would have to start your problem with "for all $a,b$ in a group the following holds: ..." but you've started with "let $a,b$ be two elements of a group" which implicitly means that they are fixed.

Comment: so $ab=b^4a$ applies only to that element? It doesn't mean the binary operation a*b is defined so? I thought its the definition of binary operation in that group...

Comment: @johny You are correct: it only applies to that particular element, not to the whole operation.

Comment: so I can't expand $ (ab)^6$ as  $a^6b^6$. right?

Comment: @freakish thanks for correcting this. I implicitly assumed that the group is given by this presentation. I should change that.

Comment: and $(ab)^{-1} $ will be since $(ab)^2=b^5$ and $(ab)^6=e$, therefore $(ab)^5 = (ab)^{-1} $.....$b^5b^5ab = b^{10}b^4a=b^14a=b^2a$???

Comment: @johny it is not clear to me, what you are asking here…

Comment: in the question I have to express inverse of ab in terms of a and b ..look at the full question..

Comment: And did you look at the other answer, they have done it in very simple steps. Is it correct?

Comment: Not quite; for the same reason my first attempt was not correct. See @freakish’s first comment on my answer.

Comment: he is getting different inverse also as $ab^5$, Im all confused cant u comment in his answer, so that your discussions may clear up the thing?

Comment: Since $b^3 =e $ (as I have shown) we have $ab^5 = ab^2$, which coincides with my answer.

Comment: ok but can u discuss with him to prove which method is correct. His method looks very easy, if it is correct it will be good to follow? Cant u two come to an agreement on which method is correct?

Comment: The other answer is wrong in that we *cannot* conclude that the order of $ab$ is $6$. We can only conclude that it is a divisor of $6$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80701/discussion-between-claudius-and-johny).

Comment: Yes. But im a beginner, he will be able to defend his method better, thats why I asked u to comment in his answer and point out it's deficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $|ab|=m$. Then $(ab)^m=e$.

Observe that $(ab)^3=(ab)(ab)(ab)=ab(b^4a)(ab)=ab^5a^2b=a$. So

$((ab)^{3})^{2}=a^2=e$. So $|ab|=m\mid 6$. Hence $|ab|=m\in \{1,2,3,6\}$.

We conclude easy that $ab=ba$ and  $a^2=b^3=e$ and inverse of $ab$ of the form $a^mb^n=ab^2$ and of the form $b^ma^n=b^2a$.
This means that general form of group $G=\{1,a,b,b^2, ab, ab^2\}$.

> - If $|ab|=1$ then $G=\{e, a\}$ i.e., $G\cong \Bbb Z_2$,
> - IF $|ab|=2$ then $G=\{e,a,b,ab\}$ i.e.,  $G\cong \Bbb Z_z\times Z_2$ ( (can not be isomorph $\Bbb Z_4$ It hasn't any element order $4$),
> - If $|ab|=3$ then $G=\{1,a,b,b^2, ab, ab^2\}$ i.e., then $G\cong \Bbb Z_6$,
> - If $|ab|=6$ then $\langle ab\rangle= G=\{1,a,b,b^2, ab, ab^2\}$ $G\cong \Bbb Z_6$.

Comment: Is this method correct? this look very straightforward and easy, did you check the answer below, why they are going that way if it can be done like this? Are you sure?

Comment: please look at the below answer. It's saying your method is not correct. can u comment on that?

Comment: `It is easy see that m>2` Wrong. If $G$ is trivial then $|ab|=1$. If $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ then $|ab|=2$. Also the only valid conclusion from $(ab)^6=e$ is that $|ab|$ divides $6$.

Comment: no as pointed above they are saying your proof  is wrong. Do you agree with that? Can u give any counter argument on point raised by @freakish?

Comment: @freakish. You are right :). I edited my answer for you. But, We can exclude easy concept there.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 Unfortunately the conclusion $|ab|=6$ is still wrong. The example is $G=\mathbb{Z}_3$. Yes, you can assume that $|G|>3$ but then $|ab|=6$ follows only because $G$ has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Also there is no assumption that $|G|>2$ in OP's question.

Comment: but the other answer also says order is 6. So are you(freakish) telling both of them are wrong?

Comment: @johny No, the other answer (after editing) correctly states that the order divides $6$.

Comment: $G=\mathbb{Z}_3$ is wrong. $a^2=e$ for $0$, $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 Of course it is correct. $G=\mathbb{Z}_3$, $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: but the question is to find the order? (PS: to put it in context this question was asked for UPSC IAS exam in India in 2011 which selects the topmost bureaucrats, only 0.01% clear this exam)

Comment: $a^2=e$ means order of $a$ is $2$. The order of $0$ is $1$.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 No, my friend, $a^n=e$ means $|a|$ divides $n$. For prime $n=p$ this means that the order is either $1$ or $p$. Obviously $e^n=e$ for any $n$ even though $|e|=1$.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 Let me give you more explanation. Do you think that $b^6=e$ means that the order of $b$ is $6$? Have a look at Claudius' answer where he shows that $b^3=e$ has to hold. That would be a contradiction. Such group would not be able to exist. It's a common mistake: the order of an element is **the smallest positive $n$** such that $a^n=e$.

Comment: @freakish you are right. Ok :D

Comment: @freakish I edited my answer. Look at now.

Comment: @freakish One should also mention that it is not stated in the problem, that $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$. Hence, we cannot say anything about the structure of the whole group $G$.